# Open link inside of a iframe in new window within the iframe

Tags: php, jquery, html, iframe

I have this:

Div element (like a bar, with some text and a logo)

Iframe with a page that I cannot modify (in this example: google.com)

What I need is to "**catch**" (or anything else), **all links** that **user click with mouseweel (or right click it and open it in new window)**, then, **open that link in another window with a div element and an iframe which loads the link inside the iframe**, I mean, in a new page exactly like the first, with the div and the iframe.

*If user clicks normally any link, it just opens the link inside the iframe (as iframe usually does).*

I've found a code that changes all links in website and it opens all of them in new window referring the url of the link to PHP with a parameter, but I don't want to open all links in new window, by default all links in the page it opens inside of a iframe (_self) in html, but if the user wants to open it in new window, I want to allow that, but opening it new window with a div element and an iframe which loads the link inside the iframe...

Comment: Your post is very hard to understand. Couldn't you consider some changes to make it more clear?

Comment: You want to do a browser inside a browser...?

Comment: Please let us know if the iframe contains data from different domain. In my answer, I assumed that it does.

Comment: Yes, the iframe contains a website from another domain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is **not possible to interact with anything in iframe within different domain**. You must use HTTP PHP proxy that will edit the page you display so all links DO redirect on your site.
So the solution would be to have a PHP script that downloads the site you display in iframe, chang ALL links from `http://differentsite.com/path/file.php` to `http://mysite.com/script.php?path=path/file.php` so that if the user clicks the link, he gets in your IFRAME view again.
This is how HTTP proxies do work.

Answer (score 1):

From your current question, I understand that you want links to NOT open in a new tab, and to replace the page currently open in the iframe.
Short answer: not possible.
Full answer:
1) Links using `target="_blank"` cannot be edited inside an iframe hosted on a separate site. This is because of the Same Origin Policy.
2) In theory, you cannot ever override what the user wants, even if you could control the `iframe` content. Specifically, when a user clicks "open in a new tab," this can never be overridden.